# How to connect my project to the sql Express on another pc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have SQLExpress on pc1 and pc2, when i connect from pc2 to pc1 using SQLExpress it connects fine, but when i try to connect using visual studio code it gives me an error(login failed for user'Laptop***\Guest)

I did all the tpc setup on pc1 and i did a test with sqlepress and it works when i connect using sqlexpress

> add name="connstring" connectionString="Data Source=ipAddress-of-pc1,1433; Initial Catalog=NelinhaDB; user=*****; password=*****"

Comment: What do you mean you connect from PC1 to PC2 using SQL Express? SQL Express is a data engine; it doesn't connect to things you connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to SQL server remotly you need to use a software - like Sql Server Management studio

**Follow these Instructions:-**
Start SQL Server Browser service if it’s not started yet. SQL Server Browser listens for incoming requests for Microsoft SQL Server resources and provides information about SQL Server instances installed on the computer.
Enable TCP/IP protocol for SQL Server 2008 Express to accept remote connection.
(Optional) Change Server Authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication. By default, SQL Server 2008 Express allows only Windows Authentication mode so you can connect to the SQL Server with current user log-on credential. If you want to specify user for connect to the SQL Server, you have to change Server Authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication.

Further study this link:-https://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/